# Missing example data when importing openapi3 in postman v7.9.0

Tags: swagger, postman, openapi

I'm importing a swagger openapi 3.0.0 file in Postman. I have some example data in swagger that I'd like to be synchronized in the postman collection.

Example of example data:

```
RestaurantPayload:
  type: object
  properties:
    google_places_id:
      type: number
      format: integer
    name:
      type: string
    city:
      type: string
    cover_image:
      type: string
    latitude:
      type: number
      format: double
    longitude:
      type: number
      format: double
    rating:
      type: number
      format: float
    categories:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
  example:
    google_places_id: 561
    name: "Very cool restaurant"
    city: "Rome"
    cover_image: "http://my-picture-url.jpg"
    latitude: 39.485855
    longitude: 49.48585747
    rating: 4
    categories: [
      "sushi"]
```

I tried three different ways:

1- Importing the JSON/YAML as it's exported from swagger directly in Postman. It works and I get the collection with all the methods I'm looking for BUT I'm missing example data. For instance

[image]

2- Converting the openapi file to postman using the postman command line converter (https://github.com/postmanlabs/openapi-to-postman)
Same situation, example data is missing

3- Using an external service as APImatic (https://www.apimatic.io)
This is the only way I managed to get a Postman JSON which - once imported in the postman app - keeps all example data in place

[image]

I'd really like NOT to need an external service to perform this task and to be able instead to translate my openapi specifications to postman with all the example data with a command line tool or something similar.

Do you happen to know why is this happening and how I can get what I need?

Thank you
Marco

Edit: the APImatic solution doesn't seem to be viable because it breaks the endpoints.

APImatic:
[image]

YAML import from Swagger

[image]

So I'm stuck, one import method breaks the endpoints while the other breaks the examples :-/

Comment: This feels like a question that you should be asking the Postman team via the GH repo, this could be a feature that's simply not there yet - You're not going to get the response you need here. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues

Comment: I hear you. Since the apimatic software already manages to create something that's correctly handled by postman I thought that maybe it's just a matter of tagging/annotating something somewhere in the YAML file...

Comment: That's not to say that it also can't be part of Postman too, they will never know about that requirement until someone explicitly asks for it to be part of the product. 

Comment: Are you importing this via the Import button or creating a new API with that spec file?

Comment: I'm using the Import button, how can I create a new API with the spec file?

Comment: From a slightly older version and some new features/improvements have been made since then but this should show you how - https://youtu.be/n3iISY7XZ_o

Comment: I edited the question with new data about the issue. I also watched the video, didn't help much but thank you anyways.

Comment: No worries. This still seems more like a Postman team problem though and not really a SO problem.